# Python tkinter spinbox command is triggered imideatly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently using a Spinbox in my python gui which is implemented by usage of Tkinter. The method to setup the Spinbox would be this one:

```
def _select_event(self, type, id):
        """ Selects an event for editing its properties """
        print("_select_event")
        if not self._can_draw(): return
        if type != self.event_type:
            #Destroy all widgets on the frame and build those neccessary
            for widget in self.event_edit_widgets: widget.grid_remove()
            self.event_edit_widgets = []
            self.event_type = type
            if self.event_type == "Person": #Build widgets for person
                if len(self.map.persons) <= id: return
                print("mark0")
                self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.persons) - 1, command=self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
                print("mark1")
            elif self.event_type == "Warp": #Build widgets for warp
                if len(self.map.warps) <= id: return
                self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.warps) - 1, command=self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
            elif self.event_type == "Trigger": #Build widgets for trigger
                if len(self.map.triggers) <= id: return
                self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.triggers) - 1, command=self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
            elif self.event_type == "Sign": #Build widgets for sign
                if len(self.map.signposts) <= id: return
                self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.signposts) - 1, command=self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
            else: 
                raise Exception("Unkown event type selected: " + self.event_type)
            #Push all common widgets to the ui
            self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tkinter.NW)
            self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.config(state="readonly")
            self.event_edit_widgets.append(self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox)
        #Update all widgets
        self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.insert(0, str(id))
```

As you can see the Spinbox that is setup for e.g. self.event_type == "Person" has the setup method itself associated as command (this means, when you change the value in the spinbox it might setup a new one - nothing to wild). However I found out, that the constructor of the spinbox automatically triggers the command function itself. Meaning the output would be:

"_select_event, mark0, _select_event" (mark0 is not triggered again since the if condition now is not true anymore and thus an endless recursion is preveted luckily). Of course the

self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    does not work and raises an Exception in this second call of _select_event, that was triggered by the constructor of the spin box. How can I prevent this constructor from triggering the command at setup?

Comment: Well, that's because all those functions you bind to the commands are evaluated immediately. Use `lambda` to create anonymous inner functions calling those methods.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem!